# Run code/event once ionicPopup has finished loading?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, ionic-framework

I have an $ionicPopup that has some interactive content in it - however, in order to use it I must initalise it with a simple command:

`myFactory.initialise(myElement)`

Is there a way I can tell if the popup has loaded so I can trigger this initialisation?
Is there some sort of ionicPopupLoaded event?

For example:

```
var customPopup = $ionicPopup.show({
  title: 'Interactive Popup',
  cssClass: 'interactive-popup',
  template: '<div id="myElement"></div>',
  scope: $scope,
  buttons: [{
    text: 'Cancel',
    type: 'button-default',
    onTap: function(e) {
      return false;
    }
  },
  {
    text: 'Option',
    type: 'button-energized',
    onTap: function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      myFactory.functionA();
    }
  },
  {
    text: 'OK',
    type: 'button-balanced',
    onTap: function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      myFactory.functionB();
    }
  }]
});
```

This is my popup, once it's loaded and displayed I want to automatically call `myFactory.initialise(myElement)` to initialise my content..

Is there some way of running code once the popup has been loaded?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the `$ionicPopup` source code there doesn't seem to be any in built way to hook into some sort of loaded process or event. Personally I would just create my own popup service, but if you must use their objects, it looks like the only option is to leverage the template you can pass to the `show()` function.

This leaves you with a couple of options. The first is to use `ng-init` to launch a different scope function, although this is considered bad practice. For example:

```
template: '<div ng-init="popupLoaded()"></div>'
```

To implement a more angular appropriate way, use `ng-controller` inside your template to create a child controller for your template body. Then you can call whatever you want from inside this controller. For example:

```
template: '<div class="my-popup-content" ng-controller="MyPopupChildCtrl"></div>'
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks mate - will implement the child controller :)